# Export an array to CSV failure: string given

Tags: php, arrays, csv

I can't solve a problem occurring when I try to export an array to a CSV file. I have used this function several times without problem but here I do not see where my mistake is.

I set an array:

```
$mytags= array();
```

I populate it by a loop. When I print the content through `print_r($mytags);`
it seems to be OK, here some examples of my output:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => air-travel [2] => airports [3] => security-airport [4] => city-airport  ... )
```

After that I try to export the result to CSV by fputcsv:

```
$fp = fopen('file.csv', 'w');
foreach ($mytags as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
```

But I get this error:

> Warning: fputcsv() expects parameter 2 to be array, string given in
> C:\wamp\www\tests\capturetags.php on line 55

Could the problem be that there is only one field?
Alternatively, I tried to replace `$fields` by `$mytags` to write the CSV, and in this case I get a 4GB files, so it's not the
Does someone see how to record thhis unique field in a CSV file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is very clear, `$fields` is not an array, it is a string. You need an array.

```
fputcsv($fp, $mytags);
```

Without a foreach loop will do the job.

Comment: Thanks a lot but i am shameful to fail on a so simple error. But i have to say that this function is not weel documented for a beginner :)

Comment: @user1453786 You'll need to study code documentation more closely if you expect to find many answers for yourself in the future.  [PHP's](http://us.php.net/fputcsv) documentation is almost as straight-forward as it can get `int fputcsv ( resource $handle , array $fields [, string $delimiter = ',' [, string $enclosure = '"' ]] )`